# How to get a (repeat) number that is passed to a vim function

Tags: vimrc

Let's say I have a mapping such as this:

```
nnoremap K :call MyFunction()
```

And my function is:

```
func MyFuction()
    echom ("how to get the 10 passed to me?")
endfunc
```

Let's say the user presses `10K` on their keyboard. Is there a way for me to retrieve the number `10` from the `MyFunction()`? The function is called similar to:

```
:.,.+9 call MyFunction()
```

Comment: @Biggybi yes thank you -- I can do a:lastline - a:firstline.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped!

Comment: See `:h v:count` or `:h v:count1`